# Separate string into columns by extracting al groups that match regex

Tags: r, tidyr

I have these strings in every row of one column.

```
example_df <- tibble(string = c("[{\"positieVergelekenMetSchooladvies\":\"boven niveau\",\"percentage\":9.090909090909092,\"percentageVergelijking\":19.843418733556412,\"volgorde\":10},{\"positieVergelekenMetSchooladvies\":\"op niveau\",\"percentage\":81.81818181818181,\"percentageVergelijking\":78.58821425834631,\"volgorde\":20},{\"positieVergelekenMetSchooladvies\":\"onder niveau\",\"percentage\":9.090909090909092,\"percentageVergelijking\":1.5683670080972694,\"volgorde\":30}]"))
```

I'm only interested in the numbers. This regex works:

```
example_df %>% 
  .$string %>% 
  str_extract_all(., "[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+")
```

Instead of using the `separate()` function I want to use the `extract()` function. My understanding is that it differs from `separate()` in that `extract()` matches your regex you want to populate your new columns with. `separate()` matches, of course, the separation string. But where `separate()` matches all strings you fill in at `sep=` `extract()` matches only one group.

```
example_df %>% 
  extract(string, 
           into = c("boven_niveau_school",
                    "boven_niveau_verg",
                    "op_niveau_school",
                    "op_niveau_verg",
                    "onder_niveau_school",
                    "onder_niveau_verg"),
           regex = "([0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `separate` or `extract` I would extract all the numbers from the string and then use `unnest_wider` to create new columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

example_df %>%
  mutate(temp = str_extract_all(string, "[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+")) %>%
  unnest_wider(temp)
```

You can rename the columns as per your choice.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `regmatches/regexpr` from `base R`

```
out <- regmatches(example_df$string, gregexpr("\\d+\\.\\d+", example_df$string))[[1]]
example_df[paste0("new", seq_along(out))] <- as.list(out)
example_df
# A tibble: 1 x 7
#  string                                                                     new1        new2         new3        new4       new5       new6       
#  <chr>                                                                      <chr>       <chr>        <chr>       <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      
#1 "[{\"positieVergelekenMetSchooladvies\":\"boven niveau\",\"percentage\":9… 9.09090909… 19.84341873… 81.8181818… 78.588214… 9.0909090… 1.56836700…
```